# ProviderError: submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Payment))

Tags: parachain, frontier

Hi I am trying to use Hardhat to deploy Ethereum smart contracts to my parachain with Frontier EVM inside. The Hardhat uses my own Typescript file to deploy contracts like this one: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying

Then I got this error: `ProviderError: submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Payment))`

```
-----------== incrementer2 deployment script
owner: 0x6Be02d1d3665660d22FF9624b7BE0551ee1Ac91b 
user1: 0x735113e044BFce4DebA5da7BfBc96A3e6A96F6Da
owner balance: 340282366920938463463.319096430768211455
user1 balance: 0.0
ProviderError: submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Payment))
    at HttpProvider.request (...my_project/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at HDWalletProvider.request (...my_project/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:182:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (...my_project/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I am not sure what happened... My Hardhat can run Ethereum smart contract tests and deploy contracts to a local Ethereum network with no problem. The contract can be deployed to my parachain via Remix and MetaMask, too. but somehow Hardhat cannot directly deploy smart contracts...

Comment: DQ: But does the deployer account have enough balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it... Do not duplicate Hardhat plugin imports.

```
import { task, HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers";
import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";//to avoid conflict with const config: HardhatUserConfig = {}
```

Also wait for previous transaction to go through first:

```
const tx = await owner.sendTransaction({ 
    to: ERC1820_DEPLOYER, value: toWei(0.08) 
});
const receipt = await tx.wait().catch((err: any) => {
    console.log("Error 001:", err);
    return false;
});
```